# ContentObserver - just can't believe what I have read

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

I have read and read related Q&A and can't believe that if my custom ContentProvider does things like this:

```
insertUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId( Data2TableMetaData.CONTENT_URI, rowId)
// notify listeners
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertUri, null);
```

...  ContentObservers do not have a way to retrieve the rowId.

Is this really right? I think I must be missing something because this just doesn't seem nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right. The callback interface does not contain info on what changed, only that a change has happened. But generally developers are encouraged to use things like CursorLoaders which do all the heavy lifting for you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

However, now with the new Android 16 api it is possible to retrieve the URI of the row in the OnChange method.

Comment: Thanks Renard. I can't see how a CursorLoader addresses my question (I am also pre Android 3.0). I think I must still be missing something! What is the purpose of adding the rowId to the notifyChange uri if it is thrown away? Just want to understand the the coding patterns I have seen for content providers.

Comment: Well if you use a CursorLoader you don't need to worry about row ids and such. You can also use CursorLoaders pre Honeycomb by using the compatibility package. Now back to your original question: You actually dont need to append the row id to your uri. But by doing so you allow for the possibility to have content observers that listen to a single element only. Such observers would need to know the id that they are listening for beforehand obviously.

Comment: OK - but here is the simple situation which is stumping me. I have some UI through which the user creates a new object(maps directly to a new row). I don't yet have a row id. I insert, via my content provider, the new row. I have a content observer in my UI activity which listens for updates on the uri (minus rowid). So it seems that *every* update to any row relevant to the base uri will fire my observer even though my UI only wants to hear about the new row it sent for insertion. I am not sure how this handshake between the UI and db should work if my UI can't listen for its own inserts.

Comment: The android way is to connect your ui to the db by the use of CursorLoaders and CursorAdapters. But apart from that your observation is correct. You can either listen to an uri which points to a whole table and get notifiedfor every single row. Or you listen to a specfic row only. I assume you have a listview or GridView and you want to add one item to it after a new row was inserted? If thats the case use CursorAdapters :-)

Comment: Thanks Renard - this is helping think it through and check my pattern is as expected. My android db syncs to a shared remote db so my particular client's inserts are not the only rows returned by cursoradapters or cursor backed ContentObservers.In my case, where I have a slider activity, it seems the user might see funny things if their current slider progress position  'jumps' to a more recent value(perhaps synced from another client) without UI feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In api level 16, ContentObserver does receive the uri, which has the rowId.  However, before that, for a situation when you are inserting a row but then only want to listen to that rowId, you can call ContentResolver.registerContentObserver right after inserting, once you know the rowId.

Comment: I have checked in jelly bean , still , It is not giving the rowid in url.